# Jquery update body scroll top position

Tags: jquery

When new window is overlaid, the body is fixed and the body top set to the scroll top px.
I try to use window.scroll() return the scroll top position, but the position remains 0.

https://codepen.io/penny289/pen/mdwYqZo?editors=0010

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  cardInit();
});

function cardInit() {
  $('.card').on('click', function(event) {
    var position = $(window).scrollTop();
    console.log(position);
    if ($(event.target).hasClass('show') || $(event.target).hasClass('new-window')) {
      $('.card').removeClass('show');
      $('body').css({
        position: 'static',
        top: '0px'
      }).scrollTop(0, -1 * position);
      console.log(-1 * position)
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('show');
      $('body').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: -1 * position + 'px'
      });
    };
  });
}
```

**Update: when I first open the overlaid window, it records the right position scrollTop value, but when I close the overlaid window the position change to 0.**

Comment: The return value of an event handler isn't used for anything. What do you expect `return position` to do?

Comment: @Barmar I want to save the position when new window is opened. Because when body is fixed the window would back to the top.

Comment: That's what `var position = $('body').offset().top;` does.

Comment: The function to scroll to a position is `scrollTop()`, not `scroll()`. See https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/#scrollTop2

Comment: `var position = $(window).scrollTop()` ?

Comment: Right, and you can go back to the position with `$(window).scrollTop(position)`

Comment: I run it again, but when I console.log(position) turns out to be 0 still.

Comment: Everytime you scroll you bind a new click event handler? This looks wrong.